# C# Excel VSTO save a Filter in Sheet View

Tags: excel, vsto, office-interop, office-addins, excel-addins

It´s possible to save a filter in Excel using COM API? This feature is very useful if you have someone else working with the same excel to have a different filter for each user.

[image]

I know there is a new Interfaces to do this job:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sheetviews?view=excel-pia

Comment: Have you tried using the macro recorder available in Excel? See [Automate tasks with the Macro Recorder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b)  for more information.

Comment: please, don´t make any sense...

Comment: To find what properties and methods to use you can use the macro recorder to record steps manually and then get the VBA code generated for you.

Comment: Sorry u are right! wow thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enumerate the [SheetViews](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheetviews) collection that is a member of [Application.ActiveWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activewindow).

```
Application app = /*your_Excel_app*/;

var activeWindow = app.ActiveWindow;

foreach (WorksheetView view in activeWindow.SheetViews)
{
    // do something
}
```